# Difference between Regression and classification in Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning

I am new to Machine Learning. Can anyone tell me the major difference between classification and regression in machine learning?

Comment: This doesn't belong on SO, it is not about programming but about machine learning. There is a separate stackexchange site for that: https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Also, it has been answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141381/regression-vs-classification

Comment: Please find answer to this question here:- https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/69524/81999

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Regression aims to predict a continuous output value**.  For example, say that you are trying to predict the revenue of a certain brand as a function of many input parameters.  A regression model would literally be a function which can output potentially any revenue number based on certain inputs.  It could even output revenue numbers which never appeared anywhere in your training set.

**Classification aims to predict which class (a discrete integer or categorical label) the input corresponds to**. e.g. let us say that you had divided the sales into Low and High sales, and you were trying to build a model which could predict Low or High sales (binary/two-class classication).  The inputs might even be the same as before, but the output would be different.  In the case of classification, your model would output either "Low" or "High," and in theory every input would generate only one of these two responses.

(This answer is true for any machine learning method; my personal experience has been with random forests and decision trees).

Comment: In my case I have two classes (0 and 1). In classification It will give either 0 or 1 but in regression it will give result between 0 to 1 (0.00..1 to 0.99999...). Are you trying to say this ?

Comment: @MohamedThasinah Ideally your _training_ data, if run against a good model, would mainly output 0s and 1s.  But on real data you could get 0.5 as an output, if that input were roughly "in between" the behavior of a 0 and a 1.

Comment: yeah I understood your point. classification will always give discrete values. but regression returns continuous probability value. comment me if i am wrong

Comment: Yes, you basically have it right.  Whether you choose regression or classification depends on your data and the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Regression** - the output variable takes continuous values.

Example :Given a picture of a person, we have to predict their age on the basis of the given picture

**Classification** - the output variable takes class labels.

Example: Given a patient with a tumor, we have to predict whether the tumor is malignant or benign.

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner in Machine Learning field but as far as i know, regression is for "continuous values" and classification is for "discrete values". With regression, there is a line for your continuous value and you can see that your model is good or bad fit. On the other hand, you can see how discrete values gains some meaning "discretely" with classification. If i am wrong please feel free to make correction.

Comment: how regression would help me to find my model performance?

Comment: When you plot your data with the regression (as a parameter value for plotting), you see that quadratic, straight etc. line for your data. But i think that is not the question here and you get the right answer on the top. I think i made it difficult. :)

Comment: how can I see quadratic, straight etc., results I am new to machine learning can you tell me how to get those in program(functions).

Comment: I don't know what resources you are using for your learning but i used Andrew Ng's course and when i want to see how my model is doing, first i feed the model with data set and then compute the error of my model then plot my data with plotting functions with the parameters regression, error, line options etc. and as a result you see that how your model doing. Also i don't know which phrase you are in right now  but i hope this gives an intuition or spoiler :)